# double arrow in beginning and end of paragraph

Tags: html, css

I want to have double arrow on a paragraph. Just like the image below.

How can I make this through CSS?

[image]

CSS CODE

```
.people-wrap p {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: none; 
  padding-bottom: 15px; 
  font-family:'Droid Serif', serif; 
  font-size:17px !important; 
  font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Go research CSS pseudo elements and the `content` property.

Comment: It does not look like an arrow, especially considering its use. It rather looks like two different angle quotation marks (guillemets). If this is a quotation, is there some reason for not including those marks in the content? Like you include a question mark in content instead of wondering how to add it with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two pseudo elements for this:

```css
.people-wrap p:before {
  content: "«";
  padding-right: .5em;
}
.people-wrap p:after {
  content: "»";
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="people-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vehicula sapien eu ullamcorper vulputate. Nunc quis viverra nisi. Integer quis neque sit amet dolor lobortis gravida. Duis eget lacinia ipsum, quis malesuada est. Mauris vitae ultricies leo. Donec ac orci non justo consectetur aliquet. Aenean semper mi ut dui posuere iaculis non at magna. Maecenas sit amet lacus ut nunc commodo consequat sed sit amet purus. In cursus ac leo sed convallis. Curabitur efficitur eget mi sit amet maximus. Proin tincidunt nulla vitae metus viverra dignissim. Curabitur gravida, turpis id auctor facilisis, nulla dolor lacinia risus, sed vulputate enim lectus et diam.</p>
</div>
```